# Conditional rendering not working with styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have this React component with a few properties, and I want styles to apply only if the property has a value, I tried something like this:

```
export const Text = ({text, color, size, fontFamily}) => {

    const StyledParagraph = styled.p`
        margin: 0;
        font-size: ${props => props.size !== undefined ? props.size : '1.3em'};
    `;

    const textProps = {
        text: [text],
        color: [color],
        size: [size],
        fontFamily: [fontFamily],
    }

    return (
        <StyledParagraph {...textProps}>{text}</StyledParagraph>
    )
}
```

I call it like:

```
<Text text="some text"/>
```

I'm not passing the property `size`, so I want the `font-size` to be the default value I specified (`font-size: ${props => props.size !== undefined ? props.size : '1.3em'}`)

However, that's not working. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have incorrectly defined the value for textProps. By using `[]`, you have made each property into an array which is why it doesn't work when you try to use it in styled-component

Use it like below

```
const textProps = {
    text: text,
    color: color,
    size: size,
    fontFamily: fontFamily,
}
```

Comment: in 45 seconds :)

Comment: A small suggestion, do not declare functional components within the render method, it causes them to remount on each re-render, take out the definition of StyledParagraph outside of the Text component

Answer (score 1):

Issue is how you define the values of `textProps` by placing the destructured props into an array.

Update it to

```
const textProps = {
  text: text,
  color: color,
  size: size,
  fontFamily: fontFamily
};
```

[image: Edit recursing-nobel-wghcl]

Suggestions:

- Factor out `StyledParagraph` so it isn't redefined each render of `Text`
- Destructure `text` and spread the rest of the props into `props`, to
  be spread into the rendered `StyledParagraph`
- Simplify font-size logic to simple fallback value.

Code

```
const StyledParagraph = styled.p`
  margin: 0;
  font-size: ${props => props.size || "1.3rem"};
`;

const Text = ({ text, ...props }) => {
  return <StyledParagraph {...props}>{text}</StyledParagraph>;
};
```